# How to configure Cloudera Search to work with Impala?

Tags: hadoop, search, solr, cloudera, impala

This short 2:37 minutes video shows it can be done.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRHTgHfqzJg

How? I have no idea. Searched extensively online including Cloudera Documentation.

In fact, in the following Cloudera Search Webinar (under Cloudera Search Components: Part 2 --> upon clicking Next on Part 1), Impala is an optional component.

http://training.cloudera.com/elearning/SearchOverview/

Comment: Hi, I've posted an 'answer'. Next time try to be more precise about your question. Help users to help you.

Comment: @SabDeM Thank-you very much. I have updated the question and tried to be precise with it. Please let me know if its still not clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there are right solutions for this problems. In my experience I just create a view and then use this view.
Here is a piece of code just for giving you an idea; too long for a comment even though it can be interpreted so.

For example

```
CREATE VIEW a_view AS
SELECT id
FROM atable
```

and then just

```
SELECT *
FROM a_second_table
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id FROM a_view)
```